# OSX Mavericks Downloads folder opens in Finder without sidebar, status bar or toolbar

Tags: mac, finder, osx-mavericks, sidebar

I have an issue which only started happening around 3 weeks ago which is when I open up the Downloads folder via the dock, the finder window opens without a sidebar, status bar or toolbar (see image). The options to re-enable these options are greyed out from the menu bar (see second image).

[image: Finder window without toolbars or sidebar]

[image: Greyed out menus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable the Show Toolbar from the second picture you posted you can then see that the Show Side Bar is no longer greyed out.